# SwiftUI Text defaults to uppercase

Tags: swiftui

I see a strange problem when I create a new SwiftUI view in our existing codebase. The text defaults to uppercase without adding any modifiers.

```
struct StatusView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("test")
    }
}
```

Results in:

[image: uppercase problem]

But if I simply do:

```
Text(String("test"))
```

I get the expected result:

[image: Expected rsults]

I have tried to look through our codebase (which  is pretty large) to figure out if something is somehow overwriting this, but I can't seem to find anything. If I change the file to belong to our Widget Target the problem does not occure, only on our main target.

Has anyone experienced this or can give me any clues on what to look for that might cause this behaviour?

Comment: Likely a localization issue. I’ve seen developers so this to mark keys that haven’t been given a localization. Look for overriding of LocalizedStringKey

Comment: What happens when you `print(NSLocalizedString("test", comment: ""))`?

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen with any string?

My first thought was that a modifier could have been applied at a very high level that was causing all text to be uppercase.

However, if using `Text(String("test"))` yields expected results, then it couldn't be it.

`Text("")` tries to use a string localization key, so if it finds a match for `test` in your localization strings, it will use that. So look at the localized strings and see if test is localized to TEST.

If it is, then you have nothing to worry about because it will only happen to that specific string.

Comment: It happened to any string that was not localized. :) I managed to figure it out, and it was indeed related to localization. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be linked to localization as correctly pointed out in the comments.

It appears to be an Xcode feature. ***"When you run your app, the nonlocalized strings appear in all caps."***
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/preparing-your-interface-for-localization

Turning this box off in `Edit Scheme -> Run -> Options` fixed the problem.

[image: Scheme options]